# Mysql output from double row to a single raw grouped by a key

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have this query:

```
select key, propkey, propvalue 
from openidm.managedobjectproperties 
where key in (
    select key 
    from openidm.managedobjectproperties 
    where propvalue in ('97539510','97939103')) 
and propkey in ('/CRSMID','/partyID');
```

which basically returns this output:

```
key     | propkey  | propvalue
------------------------------
1482195 | /CRSMID  | 814427
1482195 | /partyID | 97539510
1488492 | /CRSMID  | 1415615
1488492 | /partyID | 97939103
```

For each key - which is the same - I would like to output a two column table with the propvalues (first column the /CRSMID, and second column the /partyID) in this way:

```
CRSMID  | partyID
-------------------
814427  | 97539510
1415615 | 97939103
```

but I'm not sure on this since the group by key is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
select max(case when propkey='/CRSMID' then  propvalue end) CRSMID,
max(case when propkey='/partyID' then  propvalue end) partyID
from openidm.managedobjectproperties 
where key in (
    select key 
    from openidm.managedobjectproperties 
    where propvalue in ('97539510','97939103')) 
and propkey in ('/CRSMID','/partyID') group by key
```